# Server side sortable table

Tags: php, cakephp, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to do sortable table using CakePHP. I need to do server side sort and I tryied this way.

```
<table class="">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Eesnimi', 'Eesnimi'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Perenimi', 'Perenimi'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Maakond', 'Päritolu'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Telefon', 'Telefon'); ?></th>
            <th>Tegevused</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

And in Controller I have:

```
public $components = array('Session', 'Paginator');

        public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 25,
        'order' => array(
            'Post.title' => 'asc'
        )
    );
```

But its not working and I get many errors :

```
Warning (2)
: array_merge() [
function.array-merge
]: Argument #1 is not an array [CORE\Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper.php, line 430]
```

Maybe somebody can help me and give me a clue, what im doing wrong or how to do this.
Thank You !

**UPDATED**

Now I got this in Controller, no errors but this not sort my table again, but now its looking nice and correct. I want: If I click one column header then its sort this colmun. I think, im almost there.

```
    public function index() {
        $this->set('kontaktid', $this->Kontaktid->find('all'));

        $this->paginate = array(
        'Kontaktid' => array(
            'conditions' => array('Kontaktid.id'),
            'limit' => 100,
            'recursive' => 0
        )
        );
        $kontaktid = $this->paginate('Kontaktid');
        $this->set('Kontaktid', $kontaktid);
    }
```

My table looks :

[image]

Comment: You didn't even show code relative to Warnings..

Comment: You want this ? This is this line 430 : `$url = array_merge(array_filter($paging['options']), $options);`

Comment: I think, this helper code dont help you.

Comment: Well, this is where problem occurs. And `$paging['options']` is not an array. You need to check where it comes from and why it's not an array

Comment: can you paste the code from your controller ?

Comment: In question is this code, or you want to see all the controller code ?

Comment: what is your code to retrieve all the data  ? is code  `$this->Model->find` or `$this->Model->find`.

Comment: I dont understand you, you want to know, how I get my table from database to view file ?

Comment: But in function is this `$this->set('kontaktid', $this->Kontaktid->find('all'));` if u want to know that ?

Comment: What is the version that you use?